# Non-functionality of two tags working as dropdown on inserting a div tag between them

Tags: html, css, display

```
 <body>
   <div class = "CentralHeader">
      <div class = "LinkBar" id = "HeaderBar" >All</div>   
      <div class = "searchBar">Search</div>
      <div class = "SampleMenu">
        <ul>
           <li><a href = "#Movies">Movies</a></li>
           <li><a href = "#Events">Events</a></li>
           <li><a href = "#Sports">Sports</a></li>
           <li><a href = "#Plays">Plays</a></li>        
        </ul>
   </div>

</div>


<style type="text/css">
.LinkBar {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 140px;
  height: 37px;
  border: 1px solid #c02c3a;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  background-color: #c02c3a;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 9px;
  color: white;
 }

div.SampleMenu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 140px;
  background-color: Grey;
  margin-left: 300.5px;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top:0px;
  display: none;
  border-top: 2px solid #fff;
}

 div.SampleMenu ul li {
   padding: 0;
  }

 div.SampleMenu ul li a {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: large;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
 }

 #HeaderBar:hover+.SampleMenu ul,
 .SampleMenu ul:hover {
   display: block;
  }
 </style>
 </body>
```

When the div tag (class:searchBar) is removed,dropdown functionality works 
fine.To add a note ,when display is set to auto for ul inside div (class:SampleMenu),it 
works fine(Dropdown is displayed).Why does adding a div tag make the Dropdown disappear. What seems to trouble the flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dropdown is activated with this code:

```
#HeaderBar:hover+.SampleMenu ul,
 .SampleMenu ul:hover {
   display: block;
  }
```

Note the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors): `+`

From MDN:

> The adjacent sibling combinator (+) separates two selectors and
>   matches the second element only if it immediately follows the first
>   element, and both are children of the same parent element.

When you add   `<div class = "searchBar">Search</div>` this becomes the adjacent sibling, and `.SampleMenul ul` is no longer targetted.

If you want to keep the markup, you can use the [general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) instead.

example...

```css
.LinkBar {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 140px;
  height: 37px;
  border: 1px solid #c02c3a;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  background-color: #c02c3a;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 9px;
  color: white;
}

div.SampleMenu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 140px;
  background-color: Grey;
  margin-left: 300.5px;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 0px;
  display: none;
  border-top: 2px solid #fff;
}

div.SampleMenu ul li {
  padding: 0;
}

div.SampleMenu ul li a {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: large;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#HeaderBar:hover~.SampleMenu ul,
.SampleMenu ul:hover {
  display: block;
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="CentralHeader">
    <div class="LinkBar" id="HeaderBar">All</div>
    <div class="searchBar">Search</div>
    <div class="SampleMenu">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#Movies">Movies</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Events">Events</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Sports">Sports</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Plays">Plays</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Yeah.Got it.Does the sibling mean same tags like div or it can even be span and a div?

Comment: It looks for a matching element. You can see here https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/kqy4673k/1/ --> that it fails if a different element comes in between, or if the target element is different. Although I'd have to do some more testing to be sure... I was thrown by a few results there!